# NodeJS (fs module) - Absolute file path appends to the cwd of the node app

Tags: fs

I'm building an Electron app with ReactJS. I need to read a file from my hard drive.
I have a problem with absolute path in node fs module. The path specified appends to the cwd of the node app. How to avoid this?
Here's the problem:

```
var path = "C:\\Temp\\localFile.csv";  // The file really does exist!
var content = fs.readFileSync(path.normalize(path), "utf-8");
// on the line above I get the error
// ENOENT: no such file or directory,
// open 'C:\Users\myUserName\Documents\GIT_REPOS\electron_react_test\C:\\Temp\\localFile.csv' ...
```

Why does the path of the file I want to read ATTACH to the current working directory of the electron (node) app? How do you avoid this? I just want to read the "C:\Temp\localFile.csv"...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `path.normalize(path)` is calling `normalize` on the *string* `path`, not on the `path` module. Is that intended? What is the result of `path.normalize` in this case?

Comment: @webjprgm I've written that by mistake, lets say that the actual path is stored in a variable called `myPath`... so `path.normalize(myPath);`
I use it because the user can write the path manually, or he can choose from the file dialog.